opentelemtry heap and gc metrics
I am a little bit new on java with opentelemtry, but I would like to know if you could help me with a problem that I am facing. I am trying to instrument my springboot application with opentelemtry sending metrics to gcp. I added opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter to my POM.xml , and so far so good. Everything is working properly but only with traces. I would like to have JVM metrics also like heap, GC time all these metrics. I thought that it would be sent by default, but it is not working.
I tried to enable JMX, but also didn't work. I found some documentation showing that it would be possible to instrument using opentelemetry-jxm-metrics-gathere, (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-contrib/blob/main/jmx-metrics/README.md) but it means another sidecar fetching the data and I don't understand why the current opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter can't do this by itself?
Anybody faced this issue before ? or enabled the JVM metrics only using opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter?
Thank you very much for any help.
